# Assessing the impact of one variable on multiple others

Tags: statistics

I have a dataset of patients with multiple parameters recorded, such as glucose, diabetes, O2 concentration, etc. I want to check whether glucose levels are in any way associated with other parameters. All variables in the data set are either continuous or binary.

So far I have checked correlations of glucose with other continuous parameters. Also, I did separate t-tests 'between' glucose and binary parameters. I checked homoscedasticity and equality of variance. Also, I removed patients with diabetes because they skewed glucose levels a lot (makes sense).

I am wondering if I can build a linear model of glucose using all other parameters and then do ANOVA instead of checking parameters one by one. If this is possible, how should I check assumptions? Go through all parameters individually like before?

Thanks

Comment: If you do not quickly get an answer you need here, on Stack Overflow, try posting the question on [Cross Validated Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), where statistical analysis is on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are saying, it sounds appropriate to use a multivariable linear regression model with glucose as your dependent variable and your other variables of interest as independent variables (IVs) as you are interested in estimating the association between other parameters and glucose.

This will give you estimates of effect for each IV on glucose while controlling for (holding constant) all other variables in the model. For categorical variables, it will give estimates in comparison to a reference level and for continuous it will show an estimate that represents a unit change in the outcome (glucose) per single unit change in the IV. Be sure to also include 95%CIs and p-values for precision and significance of the estimate.

You will still need to check the assumptions of linear regression aka LINE assumptions. Linearity, Independence, Normality of Residuals, and Equal variances (homoscedasticity).